# when parsing json data throwing error

Tags: javascript, json

I am adding Json data to html div and parsing.it is working fine in local.but it is throwing error when we are running file from server .the error is "unexpected token o".

```
var data = $.parseJSON($("#json-data").html());
//console.log(data);
var now = new Date();


var events = [];
if (data != undefined && data.results.assets.length > 0) {

    var dayevents = [];

    $.each(data.results.assets, function(i, entry) {
        var d = entry.metadata.EventDate;

        $('#calender-list').append('<div class="events-list-main"><div class="events-list"><div class="event-title">' + entry.metadata.EventName + '</div><div class="event-addr">' + (entry.metadata.EventDate) + '-' + (entry.metadata.EventEndDate). + ' ' + (entry.metadata.EventEndDate). + '<br/>' + entry.metadata.EventAddress + '</div><div class="event-desc">' + entry.metadata.EventDesc + '</div><a href="' + entry.metadata.EventURL + '" target="_blank" class="event-website">SEE EVENT WEBSITE<em class="icon-go"></em></a></div></div>');

    });
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swarna123/3y4njdpn/4/)

Comment: You have an extra `.` twice at the end of `(entry.metadata.EventDate)`

Comment: Probably your server is not returning JSON! Inspect the data you're attempting to decode; use your browser's network inspector to inspect the actual server response.

Answer (score 1):

There are `.+` at `(entry.metadata.EventEndDate). +`.

They should be something like `(entry.metadata.EventEndDate) + '<br/>'`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y4njdpn/6/)